# BOOM! Perfect Clear for Mr. T

Tags: tetris

In *Tetris*, Mr. T loves performing Perfect Clears, when a piece clears all lines in the playing field. As you might guess, when it comes to tetriminos, he has a personal favorite: the undeniably cutest O piece. But a Perfect Clear using only O pieces is not terribly exciting, so Mr. T wants to use his second favorite tetrimino: the T piece.

---

Starting with an empty field, can Mr. T achieve a perfect clear using only T pieces? If so, how fast can he pull it off? Mr. T is not easily persuaded by smooth talk, so please justify your answer with a convincing argument.

---

The standard *Tetris* field has ten columns. The T tetrimino has three minos adjacent to a central mino in a T shape, as shown below.

```
OOO
 O
```

Comment: Why is he called Mr. *T* when *O* is his favourite piece?

Comment: Maybe T for Tetris? :)

Comment: @Glorfindel Just a bit of humor and a small reference to a [character](https://puyonexus.com/wiki/O) from a recent *Tetris* game. :)

Comment: n̶o̶o̶,̶ ̶s̶c̶h̶e̶z̶o̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶u̶t̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶b̶o̶y̶

Comment: "I pity the fool who messes with the T Man" - Mr. T

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can be done with

> 10 T tetrominoes (if you allow rotation – this is necessary because otherwise it's not possible to get as much 'squares' in the first row as in the second, which is a prerequisite for clearing the field).

Some explanation:

> [image]
>
>  First, drop the three yellow ones and the orange one on the left (first picture); this clears the bottom line.
>  Then, drop the three light blue ones and the dark blue one on the left (second picture); this clears the second line.
>  The final two tetrominos (green) can be dropped (third picture) to clear the final two lines.

Since

> the number of columns (10) is not divisible by 4, the total number of rows must be even. I don't see a possibility to do it in two rows, you'll *need* 'vertically' placed tetrominos and those always need three rows.

Comment: That's a great answer. I wasn't anywhere close to that.

Comment: "you'll need 'vertically' placed tetrominos" -> theorem. I managed to prove it.

Comment: The first spoiler block contains some reasoning why they are needed.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution involves

> 10 T Tetrominos.

Stack the first five arranged the same direction (on the side of the T with the bottom facing either left or right. In my example, the bottom is facing the right). This eliminates the second row (shown with Xs through them). Next, flip the T 180 degrees so the bottom is facing the other direction and fill the gaps as such. This should immediately eliminate rows 3 and 4. The squares in row 5 fall down to row 1 and the sum of those squares eliminates the final row.

> [image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I have placed parts of your answer in spoiler tags to avoid spoiling other solvers. Please take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Comment: Regarding your solution, I should have specified that naive gravity was in play, as in most games. This certainly works under cascade gravity that some game modes have.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as Glorfindel's solution but using a much more compact visualisation:

> Note that pieces 9 and 10 become connected after piece 8 clears a middle line.

[image]